# How to put comment shortcut (ctrl + /) as in eclipse in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to customize the comment shortcut in visual studio same as in eclipse. I when I tried to edit shortcut for select command it is not changing. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Tools --> Options -->Environment --> Keyboard --> Edit.CommentSelection --> on the top change it to Visual Studio Code and in (shortcut for selected command) you will have three ways to choose.

This one definitely works